# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (Python)

Tags: python, string-length

Continuously getting SyntaxError when I try to print a str and len() togehter. Please advise

```
companies = [['Google', 'Facebook', 'Apple'],
            ['Warner Bros. Pictures', '20th Century Fox', 'Universal Pictures'],
            ['Whole foods', 'Starbucks', 'Walmart']]


for x in range(len(companies)):
    for y in range(len(companies[x])):
        print("This company name has length of:" + " " + str(len(companies[x][y]))
```

Comment: Count the number of parentheses you have. Do the opening parentheses `(` match the number of closing `)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just missed one closing parenthesis

```
companies = [['Google', 'Facebook', 'Apple'],
            ['Warner Bros. Pictures', '20th Century Fox', 'Universal Pictures'],
            ['Whole foods', 'Starbucks', 'Walmart']]


for x in range(len(companies)):
    for y in range(len(companies[x])):
        print("This company name has length of:" + " " + str(len(companies[x][y])))
```